# ADD medication (Dexadrine) safe to drink with low-caffiene (Mountain Dew)?

Tags: medications, mental-health, caffeine, add-adhd, drug-interactions

I am an adult with ADD, and I have been prescribed Dexadrine (both long-lasting and short-lasting). Now, I don't consume a lot of caffeine (I don't drink coffee, tea, or energy drinks), but I do have like a Mountain Dew every other day. Is this a safe thing to do since I take Dexadrine? Or do they not mix well together? What are the dangers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Micromedex does not list any precautions or patient educations notes for Dexedrine and caffeine. However both substances can have an effect on heart rate and blood pressure. Large amounts of caffeine like energy drinks or espresso would be ill advised, but I wouldn't think the small amount in a pop would have significant effects especially if you're decently tolerant to caffeine and a relatively normal sized adult.

Never a bad idea to ask the prescribing physician what they think though.